# How to position text inside a button?

Tags: html, css

I am just using `float: left` on an icon right now because I am struggling with positioning the text in my button such that the icon is in the "middle" (20% of the left) and the text is in the middle (80% of the right).

Like this:

```
**********************************
*   Icon     Text will be here   *
*                                *
**********************************
```

Here is how I have the button set up:

```
<button class="button button-block">
    <i class="ion-plus-round"></i><span>Add to Favorites</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Provide a demo such as a fiddle, try display: inline-block and vertical align: middle without using float

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPbQNZ What about something like this?  Would this be OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try CSS [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes):

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#container > * {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span id="container">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="25" height="25" alt="">
      <span>Add to Favorites</span>
  </span>
</button>
```

I used a `span` to wrap the content because [some browsers don't accept `button` elements as flex containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276).

---

***Browser Support***

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE 10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

Comment: thanks Michael.  This is really cool and I am going to play around with this.  I think this is what would be best for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this ?

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
.button-block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button-block i {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Ionic Pull to Refresh</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">


  <ion-content>
    
    <div class="tabs" style="height:auto;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="padding: 0">
          <button class="button button-block button-positive">
            <i class="ion-plus-round"></i><span>Add to Favorites</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Font Awesome.

Add a left margin to the `span` to control the spacing between the two inline elements (`i` and `span`).

If you specify a width for the button, then you can set widths to the two child elements as needed.

```css
button span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="button button-block">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><span>Add to Favorites</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn-cont {Margin-left: 12px;}
```

```html
<button><span class="btn-cont">Hello World</span><button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).